# How to set TextBox Height to "unspecified"?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, textbox

The following TextBox:

```
<TextBlock Text="A really long sentence" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Height= "40" />
```

is 40 pixels high and doesn't resize when the contents grow. Simply removing the `Height` property from the above XAML adds this capability. Now I need to "remove" this property programmatically, i.e. my TextBox is at 40 pixels height by default, but when a particular button is clicked, i need the TextBox to expand to fit all its contents. How can I remove the Height property? I tried setting it to null, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set `Height` to `double.NaN` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and use `Grid` control.

> In addition to acceptable Double values, this property can also be
>   Double.NaN. This is how you specify auto sizing behavior in code. In
>   XAML you set the value to the string "Auto" (case insensitive) to
>   enable the auto sizing behavior. Auto sizing behavior implies that the
>   element will fill the height available to it. Note however that
>   specific controls frequently supply default values through their
>   default theme styles that will disable the auto sizing behavior unless
>   it is specifically re-enabled.

Example:

```
<Grid Background="Red">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="40" Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Expand" Click="Button_Click_2" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbSentence" Text="A really long sentence" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
            TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Height= "40" Background="Orange" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbSentence.Height = double.NaN;
        tbSentence.Text = @"A really long sentence
A really long sentence
A really long sentence";      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Double.NaN`, this will set the Height to the equivalent of `Auto`

```
TextBoxWidthProperty = double.NaN;
```